# Setting up Pyramid Web Framework | FCGI on Shared Hosting

Tags: python, fastcgi, pyramid

How can I create a simple FCGI program in my ~/public_html that will be executed that will dispatch web requests to my pyramid website?

In django, using the code below works fine for me:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.6

import sys
import os

sys.path.append('/home/username/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproj.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

I'm stuck at the moment. By the way, This is my 2nd day in learning pyramid.

Comment: Note that `~username` --> `~/public_html/` support is frequently handled via Apache's [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html) module, which is pretty picky about what it will run. It probably won't make it easy to kick off FastCGI scripts anyway.

Comment: What do you want with FCGI nowadays? Use WSGI!

Comment: @pynator FastCGI vs WSGI is an apples to oranges.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used FastCGI myself but the guide for hooking up a Paster-based WSGI app into FastCGI should be the same (ie Pylons, TurboGears, Pyramid, all use Paster for WSGI).

The guide that I found that seems to make sense to me is at: http://turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/Deployment/FastCGI.html

The key to hooking in any Paster-based wsgi app is the dispatch.fcgi file...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
myapp = '/usr/local/myapp'
inifile = 'production.ini'
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, myapp)
from paste.deploy import loadapp
wsgi_app = loadapp('config:' + myapp + '/' + inifile
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
    WSGIServer(wsgi_app).run()
```